# Finding the 5 most common words in a text

Tags: java

I have a  school task where a part of the task asks us to make a method that finds the 5 most commons words in a .txt file.

The task asks us to put all the words in an ArrayList, which i have already done. The real problem is making the program print out the top 5 words in the text file.
The only "clue" i have is the method name which is:

public Words[] common5(){
}

Comment: What exactly do you store in the `ArrayList`, i.e. what generic parameter does this list have?

Comment: Try harder. Write some code.

Comment: Show us some code!

Comment: well the only "clue" you have can basicly be named like whatever you want, so it´s none. But we aren´t here to do your homework

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question looks like "homework assignment" and the questioner isn't showing any evidence that he tried to solve his problem himself.

Comment: Jeeeze, stackoverflow certainly is one passive aggressive community :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the ArrayList, for each word in the list, put the word into a HashMap where the key is the word and the value is an Integer which you will increase every time you find the word again. At the end iterate through the HashSet and find the top 5 integers. Print those found words.